# CGRect in F# - Undefined

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, f#, cgrect

What is the equivalent of `CGRect` in `F#`: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/CoreGraphics.CGRect/

In C# we do:

```
new CGRect(50, 0, 200, 100)
```

but this is undefined in `F#`...I also tried `CGRectMake` which was the old syntax, but that doesn't work either. I made sure that I imported `CoreGraphics`, and also tried `CoreGraphics.CGRect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documentation says `CGRect` constructors take floating point numbers, so try this - assuming you indeed have all the `open` statements in place:

`CGRect(50.0, 0.0, 200.0, 100.0)`

F# doesn't do implicit conversions of numeric types, you need to use the correct literal for the numeric type you want to use.